# What is the default "Paint" software installed natively with Debian 10 ? I've done a screenshot with the tool, but I'm unable to paste my image

Tags: linux, debian

What is the default "*Paint*" software that comes natively with Debian 10 ?

I have a fresh install of Debian, used the screenshot tool to do a screenshot that is in clipboard now, but I'm unable to find any image editor, even crude, where I could paste it in order to print it.

Comment: Not what you asked  but I imagine "sudo snap install gimp" is what you want.

Comment: Most screenshot tools on Linux save directly to a file, though?

Comment: @user1686 that's true. But it isn't the question.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the question shouldn't have come up in the first place if the tool has created a (printable) file already...